sshfs receives `mount[5889]: read: Connection reset by peer` when ran from systemd but works manually
I can't figure how to enable more verbose logging to a systemd .mount file, but here we go my file is mnt-kreijstal.mount and has:
# file is `/etc/systemd/system/mnt-kreijstal.mount`
[Unit]
Description=Mount kreijstal via SSHFS script

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Mount]
What=kreijstal@kreijstalnuc:/
Where=/mnt/kreijstal
Type=fuse.sshfs
Options=_netdev,allow_other,IdentityFile=/home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa,reconnect,x-systemd.automount,uid=1000,gid=1000,user

when I do sudo systemctl daemon-reload &&sudo systemctl start mnt-kreijstal.mount and check the logs
Nov 28 23:05:49 juanraspberry mount[5889]: read: Connection reset by peer it fails somewhere unfortunately I can't figure out how to get a more verbose error. sshfs command works perfectly, however.
Logs:
Nov 28 23:15:36 juanraspberry systemd[1]: Mounting mnt-kreijstal.mount - Mount kreijstal via SSHFS script...
░░ Subject: A start job for unit mnt-kreijstal.mount has begun execution
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit mnt-kreijstal.mount has begun execution.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 96301.
Nov 28 23:15:37 juanraspberry (udev-worker)[6555]: regulatory.0: Process '/lib/crda/crda' failed with exit code 254.
Nov 28 23:15:38 juanraspberry mount[6576]: read: Connection reset by peer
Nov 28 23:15:38 juanraspberry systemd[1]: mnt-kreijstal.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░
░░ An n/a= process belonging to unit mnt-kreijstal.mount has exited.
░░
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Nov 28 23:15:38 juanraspberry systemd[1]: mnt-kreijstal.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░
░░ The unit mnt-kreijstal.mount has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 28 23:15:38 juanraspberry systemd[1]: Failed to mount mnt-kreijstal.mount - Mount kreijstal via SSHFS script.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit mnt-kreijstal.mount has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit mnt-kreijstal.mount has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 96301 and the job result is failed.
Nov 28 23:15:38 juanraspberry systemd[1]: mnt-kreijstal.mount: Consumed 2.230s CPU time.
░░ Subject: Resources consumed by unit runtime
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░
░░ The unit mnt-kreijstal.mount completed and consumed the indicated resources.

Edit: I manage to solve my problem by logging in as root and sshing into my server the problem was that my root didn't trust that server yet.
Question about enabling more verbose errors remains.
